# doesn't load url from Default Value from settings bundle (ipad)

Tags: xcode, ipad, uiwebview, settings, settings.bundle

I create settings bundle, i add a text field in it, and i need to load url from it to uiwebview. I want to add Default Value for it, but it doesn't loading in uiwebview, after changing it loads.

Help please!

```
<dict>
            <key>KeyboardType</key>
            <string>URL</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string>http://iscientist.ru/</string>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Домашняя страничка 1</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>url1</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>KeyboardType</key>
            <string>URL</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string>http://google.com/</string>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Домашняя страничка 2</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>url2</string>
        </dict>
```

and the code:

```
NSString *settingValue1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"url1"];
NSURL *urlx1 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", settingValue1]];
NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlx1];
[_webView loadRequest:request1];

NSString *settingValue2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"url2"];
NSURL *urlx2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", settingValue2]];
NSURLRequest *request2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlx2];
[webView2 loadRequest:request2];
```

Comment: how are you getting the web view to load the URL? is there any code involved and if so, can you show that?

Comment: NSString *settingValue1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"url1"];
    NSURL *urlx1 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", settingValue1]];
    NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlx1];
    [_webView loadRequest:request1];

Comment: it loads url only if change the default one in settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key you're using to fetch the default URL is wrong, nik.

Instead of

```
NSString *settingValue1 = 
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"url1"];
```

Use this:

```
NSString *settingValue1 = 
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"DefaultValue"];
```

and that will return the `http://iscientist.ru/` URL you're trying to load.

Comment: nothing... :( Maybe because i load 2 webViews? here is the new code NSString *settingValue1 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"DefaultValue"];
    NSURL *urlx1 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", settingValue1]];
    NSURLRequest *request1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlx1];
    [_webView loadRequest:request1];

Comment: for the second webview i use this code     NSString *settingValue2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"url2"];
    NSURL *urlx2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", settingValue2]];
    NSURLRequest *request2 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlx2];
    [webView2 loadRequest:request2];

Comment: could you modify your original question to show all this code inline and the plist?

Comment: Ugh. Two dictionaries. I do not know howw this object is being saved in your user defaults. I might let another [SO] user take a stab at fixing your issue.  If it isn't solved when I get back from my errands, I'll try again.